# cannot deploy customized docker image awx_web and awx_task to kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster running on CoreOS platform. I would like to deploy AWX to it. After customizing the docker image for awx_web and awx_task, the deployment cannot find the local docker images for awx_web and awx_task. I then pushed the images to AWS ECR, and set the correct image path, but the pod still cannot run.

Here is the error message:

> failed to "StartContainer" for "awx-web" with ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image \"123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/awx_web:1.0.4.113\"

Comment: Can you describe pod which is failing to pull?

Comment: @Vishal Biyani -- Thanks for asking. After I pushed the images to AWS ECR for over 10 hours, the pod found the images and started to run. Not sure what the real reason was for the issue.